# Combining Several Prediction Intervals In a Model Averaging Forecast

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Suppose I want to forecast a time-series, and have bench-marked classic ARIMA, Moving Average and exponential smoothing models against regression models, finding regression models to be superior for this specific case.

Further, I have constructed a number of separate regression models using independent inputs, and found a model-average of each of these typically preforms better than any other method.

I am now interested in computing the prediction intervals for each model-averaged forecast. Each regression model gives me an individual prediction interval, however I want to combine these to produce a single interval.

My question is, what are the typical ways of doing this? I see that we could just take the highest and lowest point of each interval, however this seems overly cautious, and in the case of a single bad model would skew they to be far larger than needed. Are there any recent approaches to tackling this problem, or for the specific case of an ensemble of regression models any analytical formulas for the combined prediction intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very formal answer: each of the interval is computed from an assumption on the distribution, most probably that the forecast is Normal with a measured standard deviation. Knowing the interval, you can compute backward the standard deviation, which will let you estimate the std-dev of your aggregate, which in turn will let you compute the confidence interval.

Practically, all the intervals will be confidence intervals with the same level of confidence and based on a normal distribution. So, the aggregate max (or min) will be a quadratic average of the max (or min).

Note that this average must be weighted, with weight proportional to the confidence you have in the forecast. You may take the length of the interval,  but you may have some reason to have more confidence in one forecast over one of the other.

Comment: In a weighted average, you also need to take into account the covariance of the forecast errors, not just their variances.

Comment: @RoHyndman, You are right. However, I never pretended to give a exact mathematical formula. Just a practical way to to give an answer that would be good enough. In the practical case, the user has certainly reasons to put more credibility in one forecast than in the other. And this "subjective" factor may overpass the effect of  error covariances.

Comment: How would one incorporate the error covariance into the intervals? I am fairly new to forecasting, however I can measure the error covariance from my one-step-ahead forecast errors, but how would I then incorporate these? I imagine some prior error structure/distribution must be assumed.

Comment: In my opinion that is spurious accuracy. For prediction intervals take a guestimate.